# Hook after wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I want to perform action when scripts are loaded. I mean when scripts are enqueued i want to take some action.

Is there a hook after_wp_enqueue_scripts?

Comment: Action for what? What code are referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` very late, using the priority argument of [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). For example:

```
function hook_really_late() {
  echo 'Should reasonably be last';
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','hook_really_late',PHP_INT_MAX);
```

`PHP_INT_MAX` should be the highest number assignable as a priority. It is possible that some other code uses the same trick though. That is still probably what I'd recommend.

If you must be absolutely sure, [`wp_enqueue_scripts` runs on the `wp_head` hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L198) which is called by `wp_head()` so a similar trick should give you a very slightly better chance of running your code just after the scripts enqueue. Since `wp_enqueue_scripts` is hooked with a priority of 1, you'd want to use a priority of 1 also, or of 2. Since `wp_enqueue_scripts` is hooked by Core even with a priority of 1 your code should still come later than `wp_enqueue_scripts` but before anything else (with a reasonable margin of error).

```
function hook_really_late() {
  echo 'Should reasonably be last';
}
add_action('wp_head','hook_really_late',1);
```